# How to correct brake pedal click from the interlock solenoid on a Nissan Titan

Tags: nissan, shifting, titan, brake-pedal, stopping

I'm familiar with a known issue on the Nissan Titan regarding clicking/popping from the shifters located in the center console.  When coming to a stop you can hear a distinct clicking sound.

After researching the site I didn't see an answer regarding this question but there is a known forum topic on this located on Titan Talk dating from 2011, "[Brake pedal/gear shift clicking sound](http://www.titantalk.com/forums/titan-interior-discussion/123952-brake-pedal-gear-shift-clicking-sound.html)" but there isn't a solid solution on the correction.

I didn't see a recall on this issue but I was wondering if an interlock solenoid swap should be made or is there a way to insulate around the area safely to prevent the noise?

Comment: What year is your truck? You may be able to open the interlock solenoid circuit when the truck is in gear.

Comment: it is a 2012 titan

Comment: floor or column shift?

Comment: it is a floor shifter.  I think after 2011 they are all floor shifters per memory

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to isolate the shift interlock control module from the brake switch using a relay.

[image]

[image]

Looking at a pin voltage chart you can see that the park position switch in gear supplies B+ to the module, the brake switch (applied) provides B+ to the module and the control unit grounds the shift lock solenoid.

I'd probably use a 5 pin relay and cut into brake switch circuit at the module.

85 - Tap into the park position switch wire.
86 - Ground to the chassis.
30 - Brake switch circuit.
87 - Blank.
87a - To Pin 4 at the module.

When the lever is in the park position the relay passes B+ to the module allowing the interlock solenoid to operate. When the lever is in any other position the module never sees a brake switch signal and no more solenoid noise when driving. There's probably an easier way to do it.